# Closing Div With Button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to open a div when user clicks to a link. I did this using [leanModal](http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/). However, I have a question about this div.

I want user to click my button (or link), and fill a form. At the bottom of the opened div, there are two buttons. Confirm (or Submit) an Cancel. And both of these buttons will close the div and submit button submits the form, while cancel button cancels the form.

How can I close the div and check whether user clicked submit or cancel?

Thank you very much.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/ssZvQ/1) my mostly copy/paste code from leanModal example. I know this doesn't show anything, because leanModal is not included.

Basically, I have an anchor and a div in the body. Anchor shows the div when it's clicked.

Here's the code piece for that:

```
<a id="go" rel="leanModal" name="test" href="#test">Basic</a>

<div id="test">
 <input type="button" value="das" />
</div>
```

**EDIT: 
This is the part I added after:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("a#go").leanModal({ closeButton: ".popButton" });
    });

    $('.popButton').click(function()
    {
        id = $(this).attr('id'));

        if(id == "send")
        {
            alert("send");
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: As leanModal uses jquery, why not take a look at jQuery UI and it's dialog methods, and there is plenty of documentation: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using standard jquery?

for your sample simple as:

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    $("#test").slideToggle(500); //500 being the time for it to animate into view
});
```

Heres the api documentation [jQuery slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Heres the working Example :)

[Slider Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eventor29/fxk3E/)

EDIT:

For your request the answer is still quite simple, jquery has most of the functionality needed to do almost anything.

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    $("#test").slideDown(500); //500 being the time for it to animate into view
});
$(".fbutton").click(function(){
    $("#test").slideUp(500); //500 being the time for it to animate into view
});
```

Heres the api documentation [jQuery slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) [jQuery slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

Example:

[SliderDown And SliderUp Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fxk3E/2/)

EDIT 2:

Still quite simple, just an if condition and adding id's to the buttons :)

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    $("#test").slideDown(500); //500 being the time for it to animate into view
});
$(".fbutton").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') == "close")//attr is to get an attribute of a tag, here we get the id
    {
        alert("Close Clicked!");
    }
    else if($(this).attr('id') == "confirm")//attr is to get an attribute of a tag, here we get the id
    {
        alert("Confirm Clicked!");
    }
    $("#test").slideUp(500); //500 being the time for it to animate into view
});
```

I have put if conditions here instead of adding click functions individually, to maintain browser compatibility i.e. some browsers dont wait for the alert to go away before animating.

Heres the api documentation [jQuery attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Example :

[SlideDown And SlideUp With Alert Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fxk3E/3/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I want the close button to be in the pop-up div.

Comment: Thank you very much. But, I have one last question. Can you show me to alert random messages when user clicks those buttons. Like, OK when user clicks OK, and Cancel when user clicks Cancel? Thank you very much.

Comment: I hope i understood you correctly, and its to show an alert message when you click each button, i have added to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To close the `div` when clicking either cancel or submit **using leanModal**, give both of those elements the same class. Let's say `.button`.

Then, in your leanModal set-up, assign the close button like this:

```
$("a#go").leanModal({ closeButton: ".button" });
```

Because both buttons have the `.button` class, the dialog should close when either of them is clicked.

One way to check the difference between the cancel or submit is to give each of them their own  `id`. Then you coud capture that in a jQuery click listener:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){ 
  id = $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

This is a very basic approach to the question, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response and codes. I successfully did the first part. I can create close buttons now. But, I couldn't make your second example work. I'm pasting my script into my question for you to see it better. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: .click doesn't work if you create the element with jquery (the button). You can use .on("click", function... to achieve this.

Comment: @Jonast92 thanks for that. citizen_of_noobville i updated with the feedback from jonas. hopefully that works.

Comment: @MartinCortez For a second I thought you were insulting me, until I figured that the name of the OP was citizen_of_noobville :D